# Algorithm to sort an array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array

```
var arr= [
    ["PROPRI","PORVEC"],
    ["AJATRN","PROPRI"], 
    ["BASMON","CALVI"],
    ["GHICIA","FOLELI"],
    ["FOLELI","BASMON"],
    ["PORVEC","GHICIA"]
] ;
```

And I'm trying to sort the array by making the second element equal to the first element of the next, like below:

```
arr = [
        ["AJATRN","PROPRI"],
        ["PROPRI","PORVEC"], 
        ["PORVEC","GHICIA"],
        ["GHICIA","FOLELI"],
        ["FOLELI","BASMON"],
        ["BASMON","CALVI"]
]
```

The context is : these are somes sites with coordinates, I want to identify the order passed,

For exemple, I have [A,B] [C,D] [B,C] then I know the path is A B C D

I finally have one solution

```
var rs =[]; 
rs[0]=arr[0];
var hasAdded=false;
for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        hasAdded=false;
        console.log("i",i);
        for (var j = 0, len=rs.length; j < len; j++) {
            console.log("j",j);
            console.log("len",len);
            if(arr[i][1]===rs[j][0]){
                rs.splice(j,0,arr[i]);
                hasAdded=true;
                 console.log("hasAdded",hasAdded);
            } 
            if(arr[i][0]===rs[j][1]){
                rs.splice(j+1,0,arr[i]);
                hasAdded=true;
                console.log("hasAdded",hasAdded);
            }
        }

        if(hasAdded===false) {
            arr.push(arr[i]);
             console.log("ARR length",arr.length);
        }
    }
```

But it's not perfect, when it's a circle like [A,B]  [B,C] [C,D] [D,A]
I can't get the except answer

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done? What specifically do you need help with? Surely there are many sorting tutorials using both pseudocode and JS.

Comment: Separately: When asking a question about JavaScript, best to use JavaScript syntax when describing the data in question. The above is like a mix of JavaScript and PHP.

Comment: Admittedly I might be dumb, but I can't understand what this sort is supposed to be.  Could you use letters like A,B,C,D or make it more clear the algorithm you want to use?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks, you are right

Comment: @SvenWritesCode thanks for reply, I updated my question, hope my expression is clear

Answer (score 1):

So I really hope this is what you like to achieve so have a look at this simple js code:

```js
var vector = [
  ["PROPRI,PORVEC"],
  ["AJATRN,PROPRI"],
  ["BASMON,CALVI"],
  ["GHICIA,FOLELI"],
  ["FOLELI,BASMON"],
  ["PORVEC,GHICIA"]
]


function sort(vector) {
  var result = []
  for (var i = 1; i < vector.length; i++) result.push(vector[i])
  result.push(vector[0])
  return (result)
}

var res = sort(vector)
console.log(res)
```

**Note**: Of course this result could be easily achieved using `map` but because of your question I'm quite sure this will just confuse you. So have a look at the code done with a for loop :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I 'll try it first

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object lookup based on the first value of your array. Using this lookup, you can get the first key and then start adding value to your result. Once you add a value in the array, remove the value corresponding to that key, if the key has no element in its array delete its key. Continue this process as long as you have keys in your object lookup.

```js
var vector = [["PROPRI", "PORVEC"],["AJATRN", "PROPRI"],["BASMON", "CALVI"],["GHICIA", "FOLELI"],["FOLELI", "BASMON"],["PORVEC", "GHICIA"]],
    lookup = vector.reduce((r,a) => {
      r[a[0]] = r[a[0]] || [];
      r[a[0]].push(a);
      return r;
    }, {});
var current = Object.keys(lookup).sort()[0];
var sorted = [];

while(Object.keys(lookup).length > 0) {
  if(lookup[current] && lookup[current].length) {
    var first = lookup[current].shift();
    sorted.push(first);
    current = first[1];
  } else {
    delete lookup[current];
    current = Object.keys(lookup).sort()[0];
  }
}
console.log(sorted);
```